# Elegir el directorio de destino del exportar base de datos php

Tags: php, html, input, exportar

Buenas pues tengo un problema que no he podido resolver de ninguna forma necesito poder elegir el directorio de destino al exportar base de datos, el mismo depende del codigo.

```
define("BACKUP_DIR", '../respaldos');
```

cuando lo borro me genera un error, pero al dejar vacio el parametro me crea la carpeta BACKUP_DIR, intente buscar una manera de que el usuario eligiera con un input file, la ruta donde se guardaria pero no se puede hacer sin que el usuario obtenga un archivo.

Mi pregunta es, como hago que despues de darle a un boton "exportar" me cargue el menu de "explorar" donde pueda elegir SOLO una ruta para guardar mi copia de base de datos en la pc

Comment: Si un navegador pudiera escribir cualquier archivo en cualquier lugar en la PC sería una gran brecha de seguridad. Da por hecho que el destino será `Descargas`, a menos que el usuario haya configurado el navegador a otro destino, incluso haber seleccionado para preguntar por el destino en cada descarga.

Comment: si alguna de las respuesta que te dieron responde tu duda recuerda marcarla como respondida/resuelta.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

Desde `php` no se puede; pero si puedes forzar a el navegador a mostrar el dialogo de `SaveAs` cuando intente descargar un archivo:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67806663/17161735

```
async function handleSaveImg(event){
  const image = await new Promise( (res) => canvas.toBlob( res ) );
  if( window.showSaveFilePicker ) {
    const handle = await showSaveFilePicker();
    const writable = await handle.createWritable();
    await writable.write( image );
    writable.close();
  }
  else {
    const saveImg = document.createElement( "a" );
    saveImg.href = URL.createObjectURL( image );
    saveImg.download= "image.png";
    saveImg.click();
    setTimeout(() => URL.revokeObjectURL( saveImg.href ), 60000 );
  }
}
```

por lo menos con esta opcions forzaras al usuario a escojer una carpeta; lamentablemente esta carpeta no puede ser sugerida al navegador.

Comment: sinceramente, no supe como usar ese codigo, coloque donde lo coloque o sea como sea que lo llame simplemente lo ignora y guarda el archivo en la ruta predeterminada

Comment: @JesusPiña y entonces tu supones que yo debo adivinar en que y como has usado el codigo? jajajajaja

Comment: @JesusPiña si tienes algun problema, error Etc... debes presentar el codigo que estas usando completo y como lo implementaste ... y cual es el error que tienes... decir no me funciona esto ... crees que ayuda en algo???

Comment: y trata de hacer un post por cada pregunta individual que tengas.

Comment: literalmente solo buscaba un ejemplo del código que pusiste arriba para hacerme una idea, pero... ¿sale más fácil que pegue el módulo completo aquí  (que de por si es largo) y me ponga a ajustar las tabulaciones que se descuadren? Lo siento, pero para eso sale más fácil seguir con ensayo y error a ver si encuentro alguna alternativa...

Comment: @JesusPiña como quieras ...