# Asignar una ruta dinámica a la creación de un .txt de PHP con fopen()

Tags: php, fopen

Estoy generando un archivo txt desde PHP con la sentencia

```
$file = fopen("C:/Users/luisj/Desktop/MAESTRO.txt", "w");
```

Cuando ejecuto el código se crea sin problema el archivo, porque es la ruta de mi computadora, sin embargo, cuando el código es ejecutado en otra PC, la ruta resulta inaccesible, tengo que cambiar manualmente la ruta de cada una de las computadoras, hay alguna forma de pedir una ruta como variable en un form, para hacer algo asi:

```
$file = fopen("$ruta", "w");
```

O existe alguna forma de usar variables de entorno de Windows para que el archivo siempre se vaya ya sea a escritorio o a descargas.

Espero haber sido claro, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: lo que estas intentando se llama crear el path ... (Location) del archivo... mi pregunta es: si estas usando un servidor ... en que lugar dentro de tu servidor relativo a tu proyecto esta el directorio para guardar ese archivo???

Comment: recuerda que php se ejecuta en un servidor... no tiene nada que ver con el formulario... ni con html ni con sql

Comment: si lo que buscas es poder descargar archivos a un lugar de tu PC, eso no se puede.... pero tienes que aclarar que es lo que quieres hacer ... realmente ya que no queda claro

Comment: Hola, en efecto, tengo un servidor, desde ahi se ejecuta el PHP, el usuario genera el txt y este debe ser guardado en su computadora, cuando lo hago en la mía funciona perfecto, sin embargo, quiero que la ruta sea general para cualquier usuario Windows que entre, o en su defecto que de la opción de elegir la ruta de guardado

Comment: no se puede, como indicas lo hace en tu servidor por que el servidor esta en tu pc... y tienen todo eso accesible lo cual no ocurrira en las pc de otros usuarios; a menos que instales un servidor en cada uno de ellos ... confirma esto ultimo... si es lo que piensas hacer..

Comment: No la idea es que el servidor atienda las peticiones de todos, o hay alguna forma de dar a elegir al usuario donde se guarda el archivo

Comment: a nivel de su PC no lo hay ... el navegador es un sandbox que no deja hacer cosas fuera de el ... por proteccion pero ya he dado una respuesta a eso aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/555974/46896

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Elegir el directorio de destino del exportar base de datos php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/555856/elegir-el-directorio-de-destino-del-exportar-base-de-datos-php)

Comment: No se entiende mucho tu pregunta ni por qué usas `fopen` para este caso. ¿El archivo no existe de antemano en el servidor y todos los clientes irán a buscarlo a ese servidor? Entonces lo que debes es exponer el archivo como descarga y que cada cliente elija dónde quiere guardarlo cuando lo descargue. [Lee la doc sobre `readfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), pues me parece que esto es lo que necesitas para tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

según sea la version de Windows... (y quizás el lenguaje) vas a encontrar diferentes posibilidades para encontrar el directorio.

Quizas puedas buscar varias opciones hasta encontrarlo.

quizas una función como esta te sirva

```
<?php 

/* 
 * @param string/array $ParSubdir subdirectorio/s a agregar en la busqueda
 */
function BuscoUsuDir( $ParSubdir )
{   
    // Inicializo Variables
        $cRetVal = false;

        // Agrega un elemento por cada subdirectorio a buscar 
        $aSubdir = ['download', 'descargas'];

    // Si estoy en windows...saco el directorio home de usuario
        $cBaseDir = getenv('USERPROFILE');

        if ( empty($cBaseDir) )
        {
            die('Error: no se encontró Directorio home del usuario. ¿es windows?');
        }
        else
        {
            // Agrego parámetro recibido
            if (!empty( $ParSubdir ) )
            {
                if ( is_string( $ParSubdir ) )
                {
                    $aSubdir[] = $ParSubdir; 
                }
                elseif (is_array($ParSubdir) )
                {
                    foreach ($ParSubdir as $value) 
                    {
                        if ( is_string( $value ) )
                        {
                            if ( !empty($value) )
                            {
                                $aSubdir[] = $value;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            die ('Error: $ParSubdir tiene elemento del tipo '.gettype($value).' debe ser string o array de strings ');
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    die ('Error: $ParSubdir es '.gettype($ParSubdir).' debe ser string o array de strings ');
                }
            }
        
            //Agrego CamelCase para cada subdir declarado
            foreach ($aSubdir as $cSubdir) 
            {
                array_unshift($aSubdir, ucfirst(strtolower($cSubdir)) );
            }

            foreach ($aSubdir as $cSubdir) 
            {
                $cBuscoDir = $cBaseDir.'/'.$cSubdir;
                if ( is_dir( $cBuscoDir ) )
                {
                    if ( is_writeable( $cBuscoDir ) )
                    {
                        $cRetVal = $cBuscoDir;
                        break;
                    }
                    die('Error:  No se puede escribir en directorio: '.$cBuscoDir );
                }
            }
        }

    return $cRetVal;
}


if ( !BuscoUsuDir() )
{
    die ('Error: Directorio no encontrado ');
}

// A partir de acá va el resto de tu codigo. 

?>
```